# Does passing a reference into a BackgroundTaskQueue work item cause the calling class to be held in memory?

Tags: c#, service-provider, ihostedservice, background-task-queue

I have the standard **Queued Background Tasks** setup defined in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio).

When using this service to queue items, via `QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(Task workItem)`, what is the effect of passing in references from the calling class?

For example:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly IBackgroundTaskQueue _backgroundTaskQueue;
    private readonly IHeavyTaskService _heavyTaskService;

    public SomeClass(IBackgroundTaskQueue backgroundTaskQueue, IHeavyTaskService heavyTaskService) 
    {
        _backgroundTaskQueue = backgroundTaskQueue;
        _heavyTaskService = heavyTaskService;
    }

    public async Task DoSomeWork() 
    {
        await _backgroundTaskQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(async (cancellationToken) =>  
        {
            await _heavyTaskService.PerformTask();
        });

        ... Some other work ...
    }
}
```

1. Does this hold a reference to the `SomeClass` instance open till the work item is completed?
2. Is this an issue beyond holding memory?
3. Would this be an issue if the `SomeClass` instance is large (memory wise)?
4. Would this also hold the instance that instantiated the `SomeClass` instance open (even if instantiated via DI)?
5. Could theoretically the instance be garbage collected before the task completes causing an error?

By "open" I mean prevent clean up of the memory.

Finally, is there a solution to not passing in a reference, say using the service provider? So that the BackgroundTaskQueue can create the IHeavyTaskService instead when the workItem is being processed?

```
public class BackgroundTaskQueue : IBackgroundTaskQueue
{
    private readonly Channel<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> _queue;

    public async ValueTask QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(
        Func<IServiceProvider, CancellationToken, ValueTask> workItem)
    {
        if (workItem == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
        }

        await _queue.Writer.WriteAsync(workItem);
    }

    ... Other Methods ...
}

internal sealed class QueuedHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider ;

    public IBackgroundTaskQueue TaskQueue { get; }

    public QueuedHostedService(IBackgroundTaskQueue taskQueue, 
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        TaskQueue = taskQueue;

        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    private async Task BackgroundProcessing(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var workItem = 
                await TaskQueue.DequeueAsync(stoppingToken);

            try
            {
                await workItem(_serviceProvider, stoppingToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, 
                    "Error occurred executing {WorkItem}.", nameof(workItem));
            }
        }
    }
    
    ... Other methods ...
}
```

And then create the work item using that service provider? Does this allow for disposal of the calling class? Should this use the `IServiceProviderFactory` instead?

```
public async Task DoSomeWork() 
{
    await _backgroundTaskQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(async (serviceProvider, cancellationToken) =>  
    {
        await serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHeavyTaskService>().PerformTask();
    });

    ... Some other work ...
}
```